# Auto select date between with manual intervention

Tags: sql

I would like to run this command through batch so I want to change the date accordingly today without manual intervention, e.g.:

```
SELECT XYZ,DFG,FGR,FHRT,Date_109,ABC
from MY_TABLE 
WHERE ID = 'A' AND REPORT_DATE =TRUNC(SYSDATE-0) and to_timestamp(substr(DATE_109,1,19),'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') between '03-Dec-2019 01:00:00' and '15-Dec-2019 01:00:00'
```

DATE_109="03/12/2019 11:02:53" FORMAT

My system date format is "YYYY-MM-DD".

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried? Do you get error messages?

Comment: here we need  the Change Date  manually daily so i want to change this as per the System Date every day thru getdate() or any other command (between '03-Dec-2019 01:00:00' and '15-Dec-2019 01:00:00')